# Installing Vbox Guest Additions in Ubuntu Server

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu Server in a Windows 8 host. When I click the "Devices>>Insert Guest Additions CD image", I am greeted with a prompt that says: 
"Unable to insert the virtual optical disk : Would you like to try to force insertion of the disk?" 
What should I do with this?
Should I "Force Mount" or "Cancel"?

Comment: Use `force`, why not?

Answer (score 4):

You don't insert Guest Additions CD image you don't need to at all.

open up  a terminal and run this command to open up additional drivers.

```
sudo /usr/bin/software-properties-gtk --open-tab=4
```

Click on `Using x86 visualization solution`

[image]

Then click on <kbd>apply Changes</kbd>

If you wanted to Install this in terminal you would need to run this command.

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-dkms
```